# Keep me cool. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am masters of masters in levitating magic.
>
> Keep me cool, I won't stop the tiny-tiny things.
>
> You can't find 'I' in me, even if you go according to the law of world.

Who am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you are

> a superconductor

Because:

1)

> A superconductor can float above magnets (levitate)

2)

> When a superconductor is frozen, it has near zero electrical resistance (electrons being the tiny-tiny thing)

3)

> I'm not really sure about the "I". It can either mean that there is no letter "I" in "superconductor", or it can represent "I", the electrical current.

Comment: to be honest i guessed from the very first line. That was a bit too easy. The last one could be that there is no "I" because it's an object and can't think.

Comment: Yes you can not find (I) current in superconductor.